# I'm using opencv-3.4.1 and can't use imshow(). thinking there's no lib! how can I solve it?

Tags: function, opencv, lnk2019, imshow, lib

I'm using opencv-3.4.1 and having problem in using imshow(). Thinking there's no lib! How can I solve it?

This is my lib folder

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vTMT6.jpg)

It has only 'opencv_world341.lib' and I want to use different functions like 'imshow()'

This picture below is me having problems with 'imshow()' function.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfSHB.jpg)

I'm korean, so I'm using a korean visual studio 2015, but I think you could still understand the error code. Its 'LNK2019' error and if I comment out the 'imshow()' function. The program runs fine, so I'm thinking I have not enough libs.

Where can I get new libs I need?

Comment: I think you may need to include the `highgui` module with
`#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>` to use `imshow()`. These examples may help: https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.1/db/deb/tutorial_display_image.html

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds I read your link and tried but having same problems... T^T Don't know what my problems...

Comment: @AlexanderReynolds Sorry I solved the problem! I added wrong .lib... Sorry man. I added release verson